# Maxifs using multiple importrange in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The following code:

```
=MAX(MAXIFS(IMPORTRANGE("url"),IMPORTRANGE("url"),B9), MAXIFS(IMPORTRANGE("url"),IMPORTRANGE("url"),B9), MAXIFS(IMPORTRANGE("url"),IMPORTRANGE("url"),B9))
```

It is not working.

[mainsheet]  [0]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuVq262QHv_Lv0WSHjhSvbgolJCWc6TuiaCvNJxA45w

[test1][1]
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HoQQQziMuIiIHoWxODG7ixQW5wk4FCK5y5cigACc7Vo

[test2][2]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Fi516nyXYvLLk3-9KPOMmwaUcyJPUubncs8ONhWT5I

[test3][3]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQiDZfoggg0xumix1hpQzaCf5UMc9o0xtkpIHDNA7mc

Comment: Welcome. Can you please express your question in a clearer and more social format. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not having "multiple" `maxifs` with `importrange`. The problem exists with even a single `maxifs` replying on `importrange`.

`maxifs` expects a range and `importrange` does not satisfy this expectation. Hence the error message "Argument must be a range".
The way to manage this is to create a helper range where each the `importrange` can be imported and the `maxifs` function applied to the physical range.

This screenshot shows the general idea.
[image]

- Cell J2: `=maxifs(A2:A7,B2:B7,C2)`
- Cell J3: `=maxifs(D2:D5,E2:E5,F2)`
- Cell J4: `=maxifs(G2:G5,H2:H5,I2)`
- Cell J5: `=max(J2:J4)`

By comparison, cell F8 contains the formula containing the various `maxifs` and `importrange` values. The result is an error.